# Почему возникает render problem java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0

Tags: android, android-studio, activity, android-edittext

При добавлении EditText даже на пустое Activity возникает

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:657)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:433)
    at com.android.ninepatch.NinePatchChunk.draw(NinePatchChunk.java:190)
    at com.android.ninepatch.NinePatchChunk.draw(NinePatchChunk.java:106)
    at android.graphics.BaseCanvas_Delegate$1.draw(BaseCanvas_Delegate.java:464)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.GcSnapshot.drawInLayer(GcSnapshot.java:697)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.GcSnapshot.draw(GcSnapshot.java:587)
    at android.graphics.BaseCanvas_Delegate.nDrawNinePatch(BaseCanvas_Delegate.java:461)
    at android.graphics.BaseCanvas.nDrawNinePatch(BaseCanvas.java)
    at android.graphics.BaseCanvas.drawPatch(BaseCanvas.java:307)
    at android.graphics.Canvas.drawPatch(Canvas.java:1825)
    at android.graphics.NinePatch.draw(NinePatch.java:217)
    at android.graphics.drawable.NinePatchDrawable.draw(NinePatchDrawable.java:249)
    at android.graphics.drawable.DrawableContainer.draw(DrawableContainer.java:87)
    at android.graphics.drawable.DrawableWrapper.draw(DrawableWrapper.java:240)
    at android.view.View.drawBackground(View.java:21674)
    at android.view.View.draw_Original(View.java:21435)
    at android.view.View_Delegate.draw(View_Delegate.java:56)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:21417)
    at android.view.View.draw_Original(View.java:21317)
    at android.view.View_Delegate.draw(View_Delegate.java:68)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:21089)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild_Original(ViewGroup.java:4388)
    at android.view.ViewGroup_Delegate.drawChild(ViewGroup_Delegate.java:65)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4388)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4149)
    at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.dispatchDraw(ConstraintLayout.java:1975)
    at android.view.View.draw_Original(View.java:21315)
    at android.view.View_Delegate.draw(View_Delegate.java:68)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:21089)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild_Original(ViewGroup.java:4388)
    at android.view.ViewGroup_Delegate.drawChild(ViewGroup_Delegate.java:65)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4388)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4149)
    at android.view.View.draw_Original(View.java:21315)
    at android.view.View_Delegate.draw(View_Delegate.java:68)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:21089)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild_Original(ViewGroup.java:4388)
    at android.view.ViewGroup_Delegate.drawChild(ViewGroup_Delegate.java:65)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4388)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4149)
    at android.view.View.draw_Original(View.java:21315)
    at android.view.View_Delegate.draw(View_Delegate.java:68)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:21089)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild_Original(ViewGroup.java:4388)
    at android.view.ViewGroup_Delegate.drawChild(ViewGroup_Delegate.java:65)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4388)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4149)
    at android.view.View.draw_Original(View.java:21446)
    at android.view.View_Delegate.draw(View_Delegate.java:56)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:21417)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.renderAndBuildResult(RenderSessionImpl.java:404)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.renderAndBuildResult(RenderSessionImpl.java:565)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.render(RenderSessionImpl.java:425)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.BridgeRenderSession.render(BridgeRenderSession.java:115)
    at com.android.ide.common.rendering.api.RenderSession.render(RenderSession.java:143)
    at com.android.ide.common.rendering.api.RenderSession.render(RenderSession.java:125)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.lambda$null$11(RenderTask.java:966)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1604)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Вот xml код:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/FirstAddPills1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".FirstAddPills">
    
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ToAddPills2"
            android:layout_width="77dp"
            android:layout_height="63dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="28dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
            android:onClick="onToAddClick"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_media_ff" />
    
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/nameInput"
            android:layout_width="322dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/actionHint"
            tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />
    
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/actionHint"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="68dp"
            android:text="Введите название препарата"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

И Java

```
    package com.example.pilltime;
    
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    
    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
    
    public class AddPills extends AppCompatActivity {
    
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_pills);
            final EditText pillName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.nameInput);
            Intent getName = new Intent(this, AddPills2.class);
    
    }
        public void onToAddClick(View view){
            Intent AddPills2 = new Intent (AddPills.this, AddPills2.class);
            startActivity(AddPills2);
        }
    }
```

Comment: а если это убрать? app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_media_ff"

Comment: @Style-7 всё так же, эта ошибка возникает даже на пустом Activity с любым полем типа EditText